# IE9 Problems with link Cascading order?

Tags: colors, hyperlink, internet-explorer-9

Ok I have a pretty simple problem. In Chrome, Safari, and Firefox everything is fine and perfect. But in IE9 it is not.

I have CSS style set up for a couple different links.

.header a:link {
color:#fff;
background-color:#f00;
}
.content a:link {
color:#00f;
text-decoration:underline;
}
.nolinkcolor a:link {
color:#000;
background-color:fff;
}

Here is the problem when using the last css style .nolinkcolor it does not work at all on IE9 all other browsers it works fine. In IE9 it basically ignores the .nolinkcolor and uses the styles of the .header

I just want to know if this is known problem and if there a tweak of fix for it???
thanks

Comment: Is the `.nolinkcolor` that is not working inside of the `.header` container by chance? Also if you have an anchor that you don't want to have color, it would be best practice to add the class to the anchor itself. `<a href="" class="nolinkcolor">...</a>`. Then it would be `a.nolinkcolor {}` in your CSS.

Comment: You should post this to .... http://browseryoulovedtohate.com/ and let Microsoft know why people hate IE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check you div like `<a href="#" class="nolinkcolor">Your test</a>`. Also it matter parent container for link. If it is inside other container. you have to overwrite CSS. like:

modify CSS like:

```
body #parentContainerID or class a.nolinkcolor {}
```

Comment: So my css is taking the style of the .header a:link when I want it to use the .nolinkcolor a:link

I tried using the !important and again it works on all browsers except IE9. I tried setting it up as span, div, id, etc... and all browsers work except IE9.

So how would i write the css if i wanted it to override the parent like you said, .header a:link, how would i write the css to have the .nolinkcolor a:link override it?

Comment: Thanks I answered I am stupid, it had to do with browser not being refreshed with i checked it.

Answer (score 0):

```
.nolinkcolor a:link {
color:#000;
background-color:fff;
}
```

Make sure you include the `#` character in background-color.

Fixing that that, I'm not seeing any other issues in IE9:
[JSFiddle test](http://jsfiddle.net/H2r6Y/3/)

Comment: I did have the # before the fff, I just didn't write it here by mistake, sorry.